# micromax A110 canvas 2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

where to find unmount OTG storage option in file manager / settings of my phone . If I remove my pen drive, message appears as `unexpectedly removed`

Comment: Is there not a notification item that you can tap?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Storage > Scroll down and unmount your Pen Drive.